# Prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|x+iy|^{-\alpha}dx=c_\alpha y^{-\alpha+1}$.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|x+iy|^{-\alpha}dx=c_\alpha y^{-\alpha+1}$, where $c_\alpha$ is a constant to be determined.

I tried to prove the problem using mathematical induction and it is okay for the starting point $\alpha=2$, which I obtained $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|x+iy|^{-\alpha}dx=(4n+1) \pi y^{-1}$. But I face difficulty for the inductive step'

Comment: Your "mathematical induction" line assumes $\;\alpha\in\Bbb N\;$ and not merely a real parameter. Is this accurate? Because if it is then you should write it down explicitly, and if it is not then induction won't help you here.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ideas. The integral can be rewritten as
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{-\alpha/2}\mathrm dx.
$$
Use the substitution $x=ty$ (it is implicitely assumed that $y\neq 0$).

Comment: I tried the substitution $x=ty$  yes it give the result when it is improper integral but I did not get the result due to integration over $\mathbb{R}$ .

Comment: Thanks it works using the substitution and using Beta and Gamma Function.